# Starting sikuli from batch file, command prompt text won't get coloured

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have made a combination of scripts to execute my test. 
Now I have a Main script as well, this one executes the others when needed.

I made a batch file to execute my Run.sikuli file. 
It looks like this:

```
start /min C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\Sikuli\runIde.cmd -r C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\Sikuli\Run.sikuli
```

Now the above part works fine.

The thing is that I would like to display a different colour of text in the command prompt. 
So I added above my line: color 0B

```
color 0B 
start /min C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\Sikuli\runIde.cmd -r C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\Sikuli\Run.sikuli
```

However, my command prompt is still not black with with light blue letters. 
The letters are still white.

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the START /MIN. You are starting a new separate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `start`, you are actually starting a separate window (more info [here](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm)). So when you set your color, it is only applied to your current window. New window will have its default color again.

**NOTE**: Just to emphasize, this has nothing to do with Sikuli.

Comment: Just did a fast test at my home computer, and it seems to do the trick. 
Thanks to the both of you for helping. :-)